# Variable referencing another variable doesn’t have correct value

Tags: css

I want and expect the text here to be blue, but instead it is red:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <style>
      :root,
      .light {
        --var1: red;
      }
      .dark {
        --var1: blue;
      }
      /* @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
        :root {
          --var1: blue;
        }
      } */

      :root {
        --var2: var(--var1);
      }

      body {
        color: var(--var2);
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body class="dark">
    <p>red = light, blue = dark</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried this on macOS Chrome, macOS Safari, macOS Firefox, and iOS Safari, and all of them resulted in the above text being red.

In Chrome and Safari devtools, hovering over the `--var2: var(--var1)` property reveals that the computed value is red, which is what happens on the webpage. However, clicking on this `--var1` goes to the `--var1: blue;` property in the `.dark` declaration. Also, the `--var1: red` property (in `:root, .light`) is struck out which seems to imply that that property is being overridden by the one in `.dark`.

[image: Chrome DevTools screenshot]

I also experimented with changing the `prefers-color-scheme` and the class on the body element (after uncommenting the `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)` part), and there’s a few other cases that don’t work the way I want it to (I’ve italicised these ones in the table below).

|  | no preference | `prefers-color-scheme: light` | `prefers-color-scheme: dark` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **no class** | red | red | blue |
| **`class="light"`** | red | red | *blue* (should be red) |
| **`class="dark"`** | *red* (should be blue) | *red* (should be blue) | blue |

These are some workarounds I’ve found:

- Change `color: var(--var2)` to `color: var(--var1)`

  - but I would like to keep these variables separate (`--var1` is actually something like `--slate-12` and `--var2` is something like `--foreground-color`)
- Add `.dark { --var2: var(--var1); }`

  - but I’d rather not repeat this again when I’ve already defined it in `:root`

Is there another way to fix this? Also, why does devtools get it wrong with what definition of `--var1` the webpage is using?

---

### More context

I’m trying to use [Radix Colors](https://www.radix-ui.com/colors), which has CSS like this:

```css
:root, .light, .light-theme {
  --slate-1: hsl(240, 22.0%, 99.0%);
  --slate-2: hsl(240, 20.0%, 98.0%);
  --slate-3: hsl(239, 13.4%, 95.4%);
  --slate-4: hsl(238, 11.8%, 92.9%);
  --slate-5: hsl(237, 11.1%, 90.5%);
  --slate-6: hsl(236, 10.6%, 87.9%);
  --slate-7: hsl(234, 10.4%, 84.4%);
  --slate-8: hsl(231, 10.2%, 75.1%);
  --slate-9: hsl(230, 6.0%, 57.0%);
  --slate-10: hsl(227, 5.2%, 51.8%);
  --slate-11: hsl(220, 6.0%, 40.0%);
  --slate-12: hsl(210, 16.0%, 20.0%);
}

.dark, dark-theme {
  --slate-1: hsl(240, 5.0%, 9.8%);
  --slate-2: hsl(240, 6.9%, 11.4%);
  --slate-3: hsl(235, 6.8%, 17.1%);
  --slate-4: hsl(233, 6.8%, 19.9%);
  --slate-5: hsl(231, 6.8%, 21.7%);
  --slate-6: hsl(230, 6.9%, 23.8%);
  --slate-7: hsl(228, 7.0%, 27.0%);
  --slate-8: hsl(225, 7.2%, 32.5%);
  --slate-9: hsl(220, 6.0%, 44.0%);
  --slate-10: hsl(218, 5.3%, 51.5%);
  --slate-11: hsl(220, 7.0%, 70.0%);
  --slate-12: hsl(220, 10.0%, 90.0%);
}
```

Instead of doing `body { color: var(--slate-12); }` (which works), I wanted to define something like `:root { --foreground-color: var(--slate-12); }`in case I needed to use `var(--foreground-color)` somewhere else in my CSS.

Comment: It's blue here in the stack overflow example you posted

Comment: @MikeWarren Oh, interesting. I tried it on Chrome, Safari, and Firefox and all of them were red. I’m on macOS.

Comment: I'm typing this from my Android phone... Also, I am viewing this site in dark mode

Comment: @MikeWarren That might be it, could you try it now? I've commented out the `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)` part. (It’s still red for me)

Comment: Windows 11 Firefox here, dark mode. The text is red for me

Comment: We need more context. What’s the big picture? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @BrettDonald I’ve added more context to my question.

Answer (score 0):

What is the actual problem you’re trying to solve? Reversing your colour scheme when a user is in dark mode? You only need one set of variables to build that.

```
:root {
  --clr-light: #D9B8C4;
  --clr-dark: #241715;
}

body {
  color: var(--clr-dark);
  background: var(--clr-light);
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  body {
    color: var(--clr-light);
    background: var(--clr-dark);
  }
}
```

Here’s a snippet to demonstrate, but for demonstration purporses, instead of testing for dark mode I’m just using two classes instead:

```css
:root {
  --clr-light: #D9B8C4;
  --clr-dark: #241715;
}

.light {
  color: var(--clr-dark);
  background: var(--clr-light);
}

.dark {
  color: var(--clr-light);
  background: var(--clr-dark);
}
```

```html
<div class="light">
  <p>light</p>
</div>

<div class="dark">
  <p>dark</p>
</div>
```